# symfony2 use multiple firewals

Tags: security, symfony

I want to use 2 different firewalls one for regular website access and other for api: for example when calling /anything... regular firewall should take action, but when calling /api... I wan't to use other firewall that authenticates user by checking request authorization header and then fetching that user from db.
I kinda found what I want: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html but I want to use multiple firewalls. I copied code from example (Authenticator class, and UserProvider class and registered them as services) then in my security.yml:

```
providers:
    client_control:
        entity: { class: AppBundle:Users }
    api_key_user_provider:
        id: api_key_user_provider

firewalls:
    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        stateless: true
        simple_preauth:
            authenticator: apikey_authenticator

    secured_area:
        remember_me:
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            path: /
            domain: ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            provider: chain_provider
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        logout: ~
```

Sadly this doesn't work I get redirected to login form when trying to access routers under /api url. What I am doing wrong, and can I achieve what I want in this way?

Comment: can you post the `access_control` section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing the problem, my application is multilingual so I had explicitly write url pattern with locales in mind

```
#api firewall
pattern: ^/(lt|en)/api

#secured_area firewall
pattern: ^/(lt|en)
```

Now it works and redirect to correct authentication mechanism